# Help with Spring authentication from a Flex app

Tags: java, apache-flex, soap, spring-security

Some background: I have a Flex app embedded in an HTML page and am using Flex to send a soap request to my Java backend that does some authentication depending on the username and password entered in the Flex form. If I enter the correct login everything works fine and the Flex app can continue making further requests. But with an incorrect username/password, an "Authentication Required" dialog box pops up in my Browser and my Flex app won't respond with its proper handler until I click cancel. I'd like to get rid of the dialog box somehow, but I'm new to spring security.

Comment: Hmm, looks like the problem may lie with the Flash runtime not knowing how to deal with a 401 code and the browser superseding the plugin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are rolling your own authentication (i.e. not HTTP authentication but a SOAP call with the username and password), you can implement a HandlerExceptionResolver in the spring context to resolve the AccessDeniedException thrown by Spring Security and return a SoapFault properly (a ModelAndView that renders a SOAP envelope with the fault). Depending on the browser, you probably can only send the response with a result code of 200 (this can be done by the View) or else Flex won't get it (most browsers eat the HTTP body and don't pass it along to the flash plugin).

Reference:

- http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.0.x/reference/mvc.html#mvc-exceptionhandlers

Comment: I was trying to implement this but couldn't quite figure out how to do it with enunciate. However, I discovered a quick hack. Merged into my web.xml file:   <error-page>
    <error-code>401</error-code>
    <location>/bad.html</location>
  </error-page> It's very important that the file doesn't actually exist; this makes it raise a 404 not found error which the browser doesn't freak out on.

Answer (score 0):

well, you should handle your authentication response from sever by Javascript. It is possible to make some methods of your flex application available to be called by Page's Javascript. So in your 'handler' method you just pass your auth response to that method, that's it.